# Vim plugin "auto-pairs" change automatic indent size?

Tags: vim, plugins, indentation, text-editor, vi

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask about this, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask here. I am using a plugin called [auto-close](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) so that I don't have to close my own parentheses. It has a very nice feature that does the following:

[image]

This is a great feature, but I don't like how far it indents for me.
I have the following line in my .vimrc:

```
" for filetype "js", tab = insert 4 spaces, backspace will delete all 4
autocmd Filetype javascript setlocal expandtab softtabstop=4
```

In editing a javascript file, it automatically did an 8-space indentation instead of a 4-space indenation, as I've specified in my .vimrc. Can anybody help me figure out how I can make it automatically indent 4-space tabs instead of 8-space tabs? I can't find it in the documentation either. Thanks!

Comment: `:verbose set shiftwidth? softtabstop? tabstop?`

Comment: @phd here's what I get: shiftwidth=8, softtabstop=0, tabstop=8. I can try changing each of these to see if it produces the desired behavior but it might affect other stuff, right? How can I make it so that it only affects the behavior in this specific circumstance?

Comment: please post the whole output of the verbose commands. We have to see where it gets set.

Comment: That is the entire output of those commands (?). If I type `:verbose set shiftwidth?` into vim, the entire output is `shiftwidth=8`. What can I do to get more output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get `shiftwidth=8, softtabstop=0, tabstop=8`, that means that your `autocmd FileType` didn't take effect. You'd have to troubleshoot that.

I would recommend putting any settings, mappings, and filetype-specific autocmds into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_whatever.vim` (or `{filetype}/whatever.vim`; cp. `:help ftplugin-name`) instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though. Settings that *override* stuff in default filetype plugins should go into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` instead. The change of indent settings would fit the latter, *after directory* location.